# Resizing window with NicEditor

Tags: jquery, html, css, autoresize

I'm using NicEditor (http://nicedit.com).

First, I set the width of the textarea 100%, but when I resize the window, the editor stays the same and won't resize to the new 100% width of the window.

```
<textarea style="width: 100%;"> something .. </textarea>

<script>
    //<![CDATA[
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
//]]>

</script>
```

How can I fix this?

**EDIT:**
I found a solution that works:

```
  $(function () {
      editor = new nicEditor({fullPanel : false}).panelInstance('text');
  })

  $(window).resize(function() {
     editor.removeInstance('text'); 
     editor = new nicEditor({fullPanel : false}).panelInstance('text');
  });
```

Comment: Reload niceEdit on each window resize !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Default, Nice Editor or CK Editor don't have responsive feature.

Try something like below. control the width and height by parent element.

```
    <textarea id="comments" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></textarea>
```

On every window resize, invoke the NiceEdit

JS:

```
  var editor;
  function reLoadEditor() {
      editor.removeInstance('comments'); 
      editor = new nicEditor({fullPanel : false}).panelInstance('comments');
  }();

  $(window).resize( function() {
     reLoadEditor();
  } );
```

Reference - Demo 3 : Add/Remove NicEditors:
http://nicedit.com/demos.php?demo=3

Comment: checking your fiddle !

Comment: @user3529020, Nice. i have corrected your solution. checkout. Added reference url as well.

Answer (score 1):

I found another easy way. In the nicEdit.js file change you have to change only 2 lines:

Near line 453 change "width".

Original:

```
var panelElm = new bkElement('DIV').setStyle({
  width: (parseInt(e.getStyle('width')) || e.clientWidth) + 'px'
}).appendBefore(e);
```

New:

```
var panelElm = new bkElement('DIV').setStyle({
  width: '100%'
}).appendBefore(e);
```

and near line 554 you have to change also "width".

Original:

```
newX = parseInt(e.getStyle('width')) || e.clientWidth;
```

New:

```
newX = '100%';
```

That is all.

Comment: I tried the accepted answer, didn't work. But yours did. thanks!